# Setup a budget home studio

Tags: studio

I decided to have a home budget studio and i wanna ask because i have a lot of questions.
I have a laptop, mackie cr3 monitors, behringer xenyx 502, BM700 condenser mic, behringer headphones and Audio-M keystation 32 midi.
The problem is : audio interface doesn't have usb to connect to laptop so i need to buy a usb audio interface again money so maybe I'll return it back and I'll buy an audio interface with usb ? This was 1st question. 
I bought 2 TRS cables to connect the monitors to audio interface for a better sound but i didn't got the sound . So i checked in the drivers is not showing that i connected the audio interface. Yes i was rushing and i bought usb audio interface also behringer uca202 i think and i got very very low sound to monitors and very low sound from mic.
I'm really confused of a lot of videos watching in YouTube and no one is showing from a to z everything all the connections all types of cables . 
PLEASE can anyone help me to make it works .
Thank you!  [image][image][image][image][image]

Comment: I suggest two related things: First start with just two pieces of gear and get them connected and talking. If you have headphones, then I would plug the headphones into the mixer and the see if you can get the microphone and mixer working together. Don't try to plug it all in at once and figure out how it all works as one big thing. Second, do the same for this question. Asking how to do it all at once is considered too broad here. Instead, edit this down to just connecting two pieces of gear. "How do I connect the mic to the mixer?" is a good question - just one example.

Comment: @ToddWilcox - why not proffer this comment in an answer?

Comment: @Tim Because it's not an answer, it's a suggestion on how to change the question to make it appropriate for the site. As it is, the question is too broad. I just like to give more than 9 minutes to read and react to my comment before I VTC.

Comment: 1) Is that a midi controller (the keyboard)? if so it will not make sound on its own it will only control a midi device.  2) does that condenser mic need phantom power (consult the manual) and is your mixer capable of providing the 48v power (phantom power)?

Comment: Where did you buy all this from? If (hopefully) all from one place, call them and ask for some technical advice; they're usually happy to help, because if you need replacement or more equipment, you'll buy from them.

Comment: I'd start [here](https://sound.stackexchange.com/questions/44184/buzzing-hissing-issues/44185#44185) for that BM-700. They don't even come with the right cable to set up phantom power...

Answer (score 1):

OK, here's a quick rundown on what you need (and don't need).

1. Laptop - Do you have a Mac, or a PC? You're going to need DAW software of some sort anyway. Look around - you can get free software out there (worth every penny :/ ).
2. Keyboard - You have the Keystation 32 Midi. This can plug directly into your laptop, and the DAW software should see it.
3. Microphone - The BM-700 should have two cables with it - a standard XLR cable, and an XLR-USB cable. If you use the USB cable, it will plug direct into your laptop (and the mic will pull the power it needs from the laptop). If you want to use the XLR cable, the Behringer Xenyx 502 does provide provide phantom power, which this microphone requires in order to work.
4. Monitors - The CR3 monitors come with an RCA-3.5mm cable. Use that - plug one end into the laptop, and the other end into the main monitor.

### Stuff you don't need:

1. The mixer. Unless you want to mix different instruments live, you can do without this altogether.
2. The Audio Interface. This is only needed to bring analogue instruments and mics into the DAW. You're not doing that (the keyboard is digital, and so is the mic if you use the USB cable). If you play guitar, you do need an audio interface. But... not that one.
3. The TRS cables. The outputs from the mixer are TS 1/4" (not TRS), and you're not using the mixer anyway... The RCA inputs to the monitors are more than sufficient for your needs at the moment.

Comment: Unless some are packaged differently (& there appear to be a million versions of the BM-700/800/8000 around which all look about the same) then there's no regular XLR-XLR or USB cable in the box, just a totally useless XLR->mini TRS.

Comment: @Tetsujin: You may be correct. I just used a statistic of one sample from a well known shopping site. It's not a mic I would use, so can't comment further.

Comment: I actually bought one to be able to answer the myriad questions we see about it [wasn't going to break the bank]. It works, once you get phantom to it, but it's not going to win any awards ;)